# Do moderators "see" who flagged a post?

Tags: support, moderators, flagging

I found this related [SE QA](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127992/why-dont-moderators-see-who-flagged-a-post-as-spam) but it is not apparently clear to me, if moderators can see who flagged a post?

As a side question, I flagged a post, it said "declined" *but* the moderator did take action  and deleted the post (which means my flagging was correct). Can something be done in this case so that my useful flags improve?

Comment: About your side note, you might have used wrong flag. For example, if you flagged it with **spam**, mod might have deleted it for **not an answer**. This is just my guess though.

Comment: @yasar No I flagged it for not an answer [link](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12000/is-rubbing-fingering-or-massaging-your-wifes-anus-permissible/12002#12002). It says `declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it`

Comment: As I said, It is just my guess of what might have happened.

Comment: @yasar just to clarify, totally understood :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they can see who has flagged a post.

No, community moderators cannot improve fix values like users' useful flags (and honestly it one less useful flag count is not a big deal).